# how to load a json into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, json, rest, pandas

I am using a `REST API` to get a `json` file as follows:

```
import urllib2
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests

request='myrequest'
data= requests.get(request)
json=data.json()
df=pd.DataFrame(json)
```

and the dataframe looks like

```
                                               items
0  {u'access': u'all', u'count': 501, u'time': 2014}
1  {u'access': u'all', u'count': 381, u'time': 2015}
```

How can I transform this single column (that looks like a dictionary) into proper columns in Pandas?

EDIT

the raw json data looks like this

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "access": "all",
      "count": 200,
      "time": 2015
    },
    {
      "access": "all",
      "count": 14,
      "time": 2015
    },
  ]
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just load JSON to a dictionary before converting it to a DataFrame.

Comment: thanks! how can i do that?

Comment: Can you add your sample file? I'll post an answer.

Comment: Can you try this? `pd.DataFrame(json['items'])` (It would be better if you don't name that dictionary 'json' as it is a module name that you might use.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`pd.read_json(json_str)`

Here is the [Pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html).

***EDIT:***

For a list of json str you can also just:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(map(json.loads, json_lst))
```

Comment: @Noobie Can you share raw data?

Comment: If `json` is a list, you should `read_json` for each element of that list. The input of `read_json` should be a `str`.

Comment: I only have json.load, what are the arguments to be passed for map function?

Comment: What is `json_lst`?

Comment: @Kakaji it is just a list of the `json`s, `json_lst` is an arbitrary name. The `map` in the one-liner at the bottom is saying to apply the imported `json.loads` function to each `json` in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems to me that JSON import to nesting containing any variations of dicts and list, while Pandas require a single dict collection with iterable elements. You therefore have to do a little bit of conversion if they do not match.

Assuming I interpret the structure of your JSON correctly (and I might not since, you are only printing the end product, not the JSON structure), it looks like it is a list of dictionaries. If that is the case, here is the solution:

```
data = {k:[v] for k,v in json[0].items()}
for jso in json[1:]:
    for k,v in jso.items():
      data[k].append(v)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Edit:

Values are provided, to get my code working, you just need the following in front:

```
json = json["items"]
```

I think this should work, but it depends on how requests processes JSON. Give me a printout of the `json` object if it doesn't work.